# Useful Chrome extensions for OS X

Tags: software-recommendation, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I know there is already a post out there for [Safari extensions,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24196/useful-safari-extensions) but Chrome extensions are completely different. So, what extensions do you think are useful? Please read these simple rules before posting:

- Include only one extension in each anwer.
- Include a description of the extension, its pros/cons, and why you use it.
- Link to the developer's website, rather than a direct download page.
- Cite the application name like such:
  `#appName by [developer]`
- Check to see if there are duplicates
  in this post by typing in the search box:
  `inquestion:this
  searchTerm`
- Please do not give a price because that can localize your answer too much.

Comment: This is off topic davieageek. Unfortunately Chrome is a cross-platform browser and it's extensions work on every version of Chrome, from OS X to Windows. There are no specific extensions that only run on the OS X version of Chrome.

Comment: @cksum Well, it's been around for quite a while, and it hasn't been closed, so... It is a question about software, but we'll see. I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I'm willing to let this fly. @cksum is right that this isn't Mac OS X specific, but then neither is Safari these days.

Comment: Alright guys. No disrespect daviesgeek. Safari might still be considered Apple specific if for nothing else than it is developed by Apple (unlike Chrome which really has no connection).

Comment: @cksum: It was a fair flag. The use of community wiki is changing and you brought up a valid point. But since this has already gained some traction by the time you noticed it, I think it can stay.

Comment: Understood Philip. And again, not wanting to ruffle feathers.

Comment: Can all the extra stuff above be removed? (including this comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [FlashBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl) by josorek

No developer site listed

Description:

Sets up Chrome to default to blocking Flash content on webpages.

Pros:

- Helps reduce download time and bandwidth usage since flash files aren't loaded by default.
- Easy to adjust blocking filter to allow flash for entire sites via a button in the address bar.

Cons:

- Sometimes removes stuff without an easy way to add it back with the extension running.

Comment: Chrome now has this feature built in. To use it, go to `about:flags` and enable **Click to play**. Then set **Preferences** -> **Under the Bonnet** -> **Plug-ins** to the newly appeared **Click to play** option.

Answer (score 4):

## [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) by chromeadblock.com

(The listed developer link just circles back to the extension URL.)

Pros:

- Does a good job of preventing ads from showing up. Inspired by the Firefox Extension AdBlock Plus.
- Helps reduce the time it takes for pages to render and bandwidth usage since ads don't have to download.

Cons:

- Some sites and/or features don't work with ads blocked.

Comment: Please make sure you follow the formatting rules. I edited your answer to change the formatting.

Comment: I threw in an edit too to add the developer site (found it after I posted). Not sure if the edits conflicted or not.

Comment: I don't have edit privileges, so the edits probably didn't.

Answer (score 3):

## [StackNotify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jekfdfagmfmibhidlkkecfchoghlldak) by me :)

Your StackExchange notification inbox, right into your browser's toolbar.

Comment: Sweet plugin! Installed forever and ever...

Answer (score 1):

## [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff) by google.com

Displays the number of unread messages in your Google Mail inbox. You can also click the button to open your inbox.

Answer (score 1):

## [Chrome Currency Converter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anbfhidldjknonaihbalghlebaijealk) by phaistonian

You just install it and you forget about foreign currencies once and for all :)

> This extension will automatically convert prices (Dollars, Pounds, Yen and Euros) within the page to the selected currency.
>
> If any conversions take place, an icon will appear on the address bar. Hovering on it will show the sum of conversions.Clicking it will restore (and convert back) the affected prices.

Answer (score 1):

## [DNSSD](http://dnssd.me/) by Andrew Tunnell-Jones

Developer's description:

> This extension provides quick and easy access to DNSSD advertised
> websites from within Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

AKA it's an awesome plugin that shows you all Bonjour sites/services available on your network! Think Safari's Bonjour collection but awesomer, geekier *and* in a decent browser.

Comment: Pretty cool! I like the "decent browser" part. :-)

Comment: @daviesgeek don't get me started! I used to like Safari pre-Lion...

Comment: I don't like Safari (period).

Answer (score 0):

## [Tabs  to the front!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hjaooagfdhdhmbfchnkhggjmacjlacla)

Add missing functionality to Chrome.

From the developer:

> Brings newly created tabs to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

## [AutoPagerize](http://autopagerize.net/)

Turns long, multi-paged articles into one page. Great extension!

Answer (score 0):

## [Aviary Image Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dafkakmjmhfnnfclmjdfpnbmdeddkoeo?hc=search&hcp=main) by Aviary.com

A powerful layer-based image editing application.

Answer (score 0):

## [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl?hc=search&hcp=main) by Google

A tool to help you identify and fix performance problems in your web applications.

Answer (score 0):

## [Edit this Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg)

Free little extension that allows you to view and edit cookies.

Answer (score 0):

## [Google +1 Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgoepmocgafhnchmokaimcmlojpnlkhp) by google.com

An extension that allows you to +1 any page from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

## [PageRank Status](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hbdkkfheckcdppiaiabobmennhijkknn) by ChromeFans.org

PageRank Status is a nifty little extension that allows you to see the page rank of the web page you are on. It also adds several other useful tools, such as Alexa Ranks, Whois, Geolocation, and several other handy tools:

[image: PageRank Status Chrome extension]

Answer (score 0):

## [**Print Friendly & PDF**](https://www.printfriendly.com/) by printfriendly.com

Converts website articles into pleasing-to-the-eye documents that you download.  A beagle could operate this app. Click a green button to right of URL bar and a window appears with a preview of the automatic removal of ads, most images, etc.  End result looks like Reader view in iOS Safari, but then, before you download, you can still customize and either remove all images or scale them to 25%, 50% etc., or inoculate any image you don't need by literally just clicking on it.  Genius.  A must-have for grad students.  There is no price, so I hope I'm breaking OP's final rule to say it's free.